# Can't run service builder (liferay 6.2)

Tags: java, eclipse, liferay, liferay-6, liferay-service-builder

I'm running Eclipse Neon (tried with Mars too) and Liferay 6.2

I try to run the service builder but:

- If I run with java 8 (unsupported, I know), it says it requires a 1.6 compliant JVM. Correct.
- If I run with java 7, it says "Unsupported major.minor version 52.0". That's my nightmare.

Yes, I've cleaned everything before. In fact, I created a brand new project, in an Eclipse with only jre7 installed, pointing all to jre7 (compiler, facets...)

Eclipse is running over jre8, but can't run on jre7 because some of the plugins requires jre8. Anyway, some days ago it do worked in this Eclipse, so it's not the problem.

Comment: More info: JAVA_HOME points to jdk7, Eclipse installed jre is only 7, compiler is 1.7. Project build path points to jdk7, compiler is 1.7, java in facets is 1.7. I make a clean. I run service builder and get the error java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/aspr/seu/NoSuchProcedureException : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0

Comment: If I'm not wrong, that means that NoSuchProcedureException.class has been compiled with jdk1.8 and I'm trying to run with jdk1.7, isn't it? Well, there's no NoSuchProcedureException.class in my whole computer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Service Builder might pull code from more than your Eclipse project setup - e.g. from the running Liferay installation that the plugin sdk points to.

I've not heard of a `com.aspr.seu` package in Liferay - is that your own, or unknown to you as well?

If service builder ran in the past (e.g. with Java 8), it created a `yourprojectname-service.jar` - that might be one that is pulled into the build process and that you might not have cleaned yet. You definitely have a class that was built with Java 8 on the classpath, you'll just need to find it. It might help to know that servicebuilder is executed through an Ant task outside of Eclipse, thus it might not be enough to search through all of the files that Eclipse has configured on its classpath, but rather on what's configured for the Plugins-SDK

Comment: Thanks Olaf. I looked for *.jar and *.class from the file system and deleted anything I compiled with java 8. I only found classes in some of the eclipse closed projects, I can't guess why were they used, but after deleting them the service builder worked ok.

Comment: I can guess why: If they're on the ant build path: Ant doesn't care about an eclipse project status. If the files are there, they will be used.